# How to use Java Collections reading elements from text file

Tags: java, collections

a text file given as bellow

```
score.text    
(1....224...6|211..4...|2..423..     batsman 1  
1..224224..16|211..4..5|2..423..    batsman 2    
1....224..56|211.14..5|2..423..            batsman 3  
1....224..26|211..4..5|2..423..)         batsman 4
```

4 lines indicates 4 batsmans run per ball in 3 matches.
i have to create an array list like this

```
enterpublic class BatsmanMain {
public static void main(String args[])
{




   BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
         ArrayList<Batsman> bn=new ArrayList<Batsman>(); 
        String sLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/TEST/score.txt"));
        while ((sLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            Batsman bt=new Batsman();

            //System.out.println(sLine);

            String info[]=sLine.split("\\|");


            //for (String info1:info) {

                //System.out.println(info1);
                bt.setBalls(info[0].length()+info[1].length()+info[2].length());
                bn.add(bt);
                for(int i=0;i<bn.size();i++){
                    System.out.println(bn.get(i).getBalls());




            }
            }

    }






    catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

}
my problem is how can i get ball,run,and no of matches elements from text file that i have to add to list

Comment: Do you need to read the textfile in plaintext?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing of cricket, so some assumptions have been made on the model...

You already have a Batsman class, but it looks like you need to model your domain further.  For example, a Ball class

```
public class Ball {
    public final int num;
    public final int score;

    public Ball(int num, int score) {
        this.num = num;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

As you parse your file, you then map each character to a Ball instance

```
for(String match : info) {
    Match match = new Match();
    for (int i = 0; i < group.length(); i++) {
        char value = match.charAt(i);
        Ball ball = new Ball(i,
                             value == '.' ? 0 : Character.getNumericValue(value));
        match.addBall(ball);
    }
    batsman.addMatch(match);
}
```

`Match` is a class with a list of balls, plus e.g. a way of identifying a match.

After this, you then have individual records of what the Batsman did, e.g.

```
Match match = batsman.getMatch("match 3");
int score = match.getTotalScore();
// etc
```

Comment: (the sign of a good programmer: being able to produce an answer without knowing the rules of cricket)